# How to add text or images on shapes developed by using bezier path using swift

Tags: image, swift, text, shapes

How to add text or images on shapes developed by using bezier path using swift

I want to  add text and image on shapes developed by using bezier path in ios swift.

Answer (score 1):

You can add UILabels on top of you shapes and keep track where is your shape located and where to put the UILabel.